# How can I tell *which* application is asking for access to gnome-keyring/Seahorse?

Tags: gnome, password, gnome-keyring

Whenever I log in on Ubuntu Lucid Lynx 10.04 I get a Seahorse/gnome-keyring prompt telling me an application wants to access my keyring. It isn't the network manager, because if I cancel the request my network connection is still established (also, this only started happening recently). How can I tell which application is making this request? The prompt doesn't provide this information.

Comment: This isn't an answer really but for me this turned out to be the network manager applet wanting to get my wifi key.

Comment: I have a different question related to auth at http://superuser.com/questions/189204/not-authorized-to-mount-on-persistent-usb-lucid-installation, I'll appreciate a response there if anyone handling this question has any ideas.

Comment: Same question at http://askubuntu.com/questions/21645/an-application-asks-to-unlock-the-keyring-on-startup-but-it-doesnt-say-which-on

Comment: if you are connecting to "open wireless" or a wired network, it wants the keyring but doesn't NEED it.  check the proof video over on askubuntu.  in my case I am SURE it's nm-applet.

Comment: the upstream bug is logged at https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=574315 - I've requested comments from the developers here

Comment: There is no easy way to find it according to [this](https://askubuntu.com/a/24716/60632) answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From a security perspective, the answer is that in current distros you can't tell which application it is. See [this bug report](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=574315#c4) for clarification from a gnome-keyring developer, including the security implications and scope of the task.

<sub>From a practical perspective I am also using auto-login on Ubuntu, and it seems that it is indeed nm-applet.</sub>

Comment: I grasp the security implications and the difficulty the developers of gnome-keyring have in identifying the caller for keychain access.  My proposed solution is to offload the work onto the application that uses keyring.  For example, if your app wants access to the keyring it should emit a dialog stating something to the effect of "/me wants access to the keyring".  This removes the need for an API change that would break current functionality and keeps devs of the keyring from getting overwhelmed.  Just thoughts.

Comment: An alternate workaround is to create an empty default-keyring and force the user to switch between keyrings if they MUST have autologin AND a keyring without a hassle box.

Answer (score 3):

I setup my box for auto-login and it does this on every login. In my case it's nm-applet/network-manager family of apps.

Edit:
btw the problem has been around for some time, evidently some half-fix got undone during a package upgrade, but i digress...one solution is [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=320308)

WHATEVER is causing the problem you could add after login but before everything else: a script with libpam-gnome-keyring to unlock it...the package to get this tool is: libpam-gnome-keyring at least in 11.04

```
#!/bin/bash  
#launch useful stuff for gnome #first unlock the default keyring...  
echo YOUR_PASSWORD_HERE | /usr/libexec/pam-keyring-tool -u -s  
#then run nm-applet in the background...  
nm-applet &
```

Proof video that it is nm-applet is [here](http://vimeo.com/19350519)

Answer (score 1):

You could try to have a look at the logfiles :-)

1. Maybe something is in
   `/var/log/auth.log` after a wrong
   password.
2. Check your autostart applications
   under `System -> Preferences ->
   Sessions -> Startup Programs` and `~/.config/autostart`
3. Check the running processes with
   `top` and `ps aux`, check the
   process tree of `ps axjf`

It should be pretty simple to figure out which process requires your keyring?